# Run a loop based on results returned from another loop

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to tick a cell within dataset2 (this is a query from dataset1), after the selected cells are ticked I will need to lookup the values of the ticked cells and do a lookup from dataset1 and insert a string into dataset1 (for me its a ⭐).

I guess I am trying to run a loop based on lookup/conditions that is a result of another loop. Below is my code and its not working.

Ok, I have made minor fixes but it works only if one box is ticked. The **staffName** in the second for if loop only works if it is 1 string, so if multiple boxes are ticked then it won't work. So I need to adjust the code to make it handle an array of names rather than just 1.

```
 if(dataSheetValues[j][0] == staffName && dataSheetValues[j][1] == lookUpLocation){break};
```

```
function starIcon(){
    
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
   var inputSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
   var dataSheetLastRow = dataSheet.getLastRow();
   var inputSheetLastRow = inputSheet.getLastRow();


   var inputSheetValues = inputSheet.getRange(1,1,inputSheetLastRow,2).getValues();
   var dataSheetValues = dataSheet.getRange(1,1,dataSheetLastRow,2).getValues();
   var lookUpLocation = inputSheet.getRange('C1').getValue();
    
  
  for (var i=0;i<inputSheetValues.length;i++){
  

    if(inputSheetValues[i][0] == '⭐'){
    
       var staffName = inputSheet.getRange(i+1,2).getValue();  
      
    }
  }
    for(var j=0; j<dataSheetValues.length; j++){ 
     
           
    if(dataSheetValues[j][0] == staffName && dataSheetValues[j][1] == lookUpLocation){break};
      
  }
    var targetLookup = dataSheet.getRange(j+1,1).getValue();
    var starToName = dataSheet.getRange(j+1,1).setValue(targetLookup + '⭐');
    inputSheet.getRange('A2:A6').clearContent();
    Browser.msgBox('Done!')
  }
```

Comment: Can you share a sanitised copy of your sheet?

Comment: `if(inputSheetValues[i][0] == "⭐");` is not a loop, it's an incomplete `if` statement as it doesn't include statements to be executed when the condition is `truthy` or `falsy`. Ref. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else. Please edit the question to clarify what your script should do.